# Has not initializers - Swift IOS

Tags: swift

Bom dia amigos.

Por algum motivo, estou tendo esse erro, como sou novo nessa plataforma nao estou conseguindo identificar o problema, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor?

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A váriavel **image** precisa ser inicializada na sua criação ou dentro do construtor da classe, ou ainda, você pode dizer que ela pode ser opcional da seguinte maneira:

```
var image: UIImage?
```

Dessa maneira você terá que verificar se a mesma não é nula quando for usar, ou pode declarar assim:

```
var image: UIImage!
```

Assim você garante que ela estará inicializada no uso, porém se não estiver irá dar erro.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta foi exatamente esse o problema, pois tenho mais uma duvida, por exemplo

qual a diferença entre 

'image = UIImage()'
para
'image: UIImage''

Comment: @BrunoBafilli Como **swift** é uma linguagem dinâmica (no entanto fortemente tipada), quando você faz `var image: UIImage` seria algo como `UIImage image` em outra linguagem (objeto ainda não inicializado), já `var image = UIImage()` você está instanciando (inicializando) um objeto do tipo `UIImage` e ele se encarrega de tipar a variável para você.

Comment: Entendi, entao significa que quando eu faco image =UIImage() eu inicio uma variavel do tipo do mesmo objeto, caso eu nao faca isso eu crio uma variavel do tipo do objeto pois ainda nao esta pronto para uso ate a inicializacao ?

Comment: Isso mesmo meu caro.

Comment: Desculpe estar te encomodando com tantas duvidas, mas por que isso funciona

var button: UIButton
button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

e isso nao

var image: UIImage
 image = UIImage(named: "circle.png")!